# How to exclude a framework/files from a build target in XCode

Tags: xcode8

I'm building an application that leverages a 3rd party framework.  The framework provides image recognition.

The challenge is that my app will not build in the simulator because the image recognition software requires a camera and they specified that in the build settings somewhere. I can only test on my iPhone 6S and iPad Pro.

I would like to remove the 3rd Party framework from the target so I can build in the simulator and make sure all my Auto Layout settings are correct for the rest of the app and other devices.  I know how to remove files from the target.  Are changes to the build setting necessary?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things either you can comment the import of that 3rd party framework and also comment the code in which the 3rd party frame is being used.

Or you can check if camera available by adding this line of code in your api usage.

```
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
 //your 3rd party code here
}
```

You can also do some tricks in build phases by making it optional. But I am not sure how its gonna behave in this scenerio.